# How can I use ng-upgrade in ionic 2 framework

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ng-upgrade

I have a code written in `AngularJS1.5` and I want to use this code in another app that will be built on ionic 2 framework. I tried to follow the guidelines of using the `ngupgrade` module to make the `AngularJS1.5` code compatible with ionic 2 framework which uses the `AngularJS 2.0`.

My question is when using the `ngupgrade` we must call the bootstrap method from `UpgradeAdapter`, but the ionic framework calls its own bootrstrap method. So any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ionic Team, ngUpgrade won't work to convert Ionic 1 to Ionic 2:

> [Ionic1 and Ionic2 will not work with ngUpgrade.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-ng-upgrade-module-in-ionic-2/59182/2)

Comment: Im not sure that's correct. You obviously can sun ngUpgrade as angular upgrade without ionic v1 running alongside ionic v2